# AttributeError while using Milvus

Tags: python, openai-api, milvus, vector-database

[AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'. Can anyone help to resolve why I'm getting this error in last for loop. Here I'm using open Ai api and getting embedded data for pdf text and now I want to store it on milvus database which is already running in background on docker. I'm beginner did all this from internet help but here I'm stuck please help me guys.]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxfWv.png)